# SVG map onclick background color should active black "#000"

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this SVG India map in my project, on mouse hover colors are changing, but I need if user click on any State then it should redirect to other page and background color should active as Black "#000" of that State.

http://www.acmearchitectural.com/indiamapsvgfiles/map.html#

I am trying below jquery code but no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    $('path[id^="select"]').click(function(){    
        $(this).css('background-color',"#ccc") 
    })
})
```

please help me out in this how i can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of that path, you will want to set the fill css attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    $('path[id^="select"]').click(function(){    
        $(this).css('fill',"#000") 
    })
})
```

That being said, in the example that you linked, there are events that are already setting this value so if it's moused over and out it will reset back to the original color.  Do you have control over those events?

Answer (score 0):

The SVG you have linked has an event preset for each State `<path id="map_1" onclick="return get_state('map_1');"...` and you can use it by adding the `get_state` function (the second option).

Or using JQuery to add the click event but with the correct selector `map_` and not `select` (the first option). The selector `[id^="...."]` means `id` `starts with` "`....`".

**First Option**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('path[id^="map_"]').click(function() {
     $(this).css('stroke', "#ff0000");
   });
 });
```

**Second Option**

```
 function get_state(map) {
   $('#' + map).css('fill', '#000000');
   alert(map);
 }
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c4d7p13z/7/)